# Leak? dateFromComponents surely returns autoreleased object, no?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nscalendar

```
-(NSDate *)dateFromDate:(NSDate *)inDate withNewTime:(NSDateComponents *)inTimeComponents {

NSCalendarUnit unitFlags = NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit;
NSDateComponents *newComponents = [self.sysCalendar components:unitFlags fromDate:inDate];
[newComponents setHour:[inTimeComponents hour]];
[newComponents setMinute:[inTimeComponents minute]];
return [self.sysCalendar dateFromComponents:newComponents];
```

}

I can't figure why this would leak. Would this not return an autoreased object? It works as intended, but when I run on instruments, it appears that a date object is leaking and the stack indicates it is created here.

sysCalendar is a property with the following getter:

```
-(NSCalendar *)sysCalendar {
if (sysCalendar != nil) {
    return sysCalendar;
}

self.sysCalendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
return sysCalendar;
```

}

Comment: Note that *that* type of getter is dangerous in that it is a getter that can cause mutation.

Comment: I would like to know more about what you say. I have seen it done several ways and I am unsure of the benefits/pitfalls of the variations. Thank you much for the input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When Instruments shows you where a leak occurs, it is actually showing you where the leaked object is created.

In this case it seems that the object created here is not being properly released elsewhere.

Comment: makes sense, but I expect that it is returning an autoreleased object and I don't find anywhere that I am retaining or copying it on receipt. A typical call: NSDate *newFinishTimeAndDate = [self dateFromDate:self.startTimeAndDate withNewTime:self.defaultFinishTime];

Comment: sure enough, while I was not retaining the returned date, under certain conditions I was copying it to another variable as the initial set value and that was not being released properly. Thanks for the shove. I did not really understand how instruments was not showing me where the leak was, just where the object was created.

Comment: It was being assigned to a property and, in fact retained there. I know enough to understand that I would not want to retain it prior to assignment. I missed the branch of which in fact was making a copy for other purposes and so increased the ref count, subsequently causing a leak. I added autorelease call to that line and I do appear to be leak free. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Just to be clear: you're saying an NSDate object is leaking, not an NSDateComponents object, right?

So Leaks can't generally tell you where you may have forgotten to release the date that was created here in this return statement. It's just telling you this is where it was created.

So look to see what you do with this new NSDate after you get it back from this method.

Comment: thanks i am studying that more now. It does indicate the leaking object is NSDate object, not NSDateComponents.

Comment: Thanks a bunch Firoze, your inquiry and suggestion did help a bunch. Abizem did give the same info just a moment before you did.